# Different results when parsing after using FileReader

Tags: javascript, parsing, object, filereader

***Question:***  How to get the same result when parsing the data through the `FileReader` as when passing the data via the variable. Which is three different objects one with the `key` and `value` of `when` `who` and `where`. Example of this is shown in the first Image.

I have to parse the data from a file, the file always keeps the same format but the values may change.

This is the function I am currently using to parse the data:

```
function parseData(src) {
  var blocks = src.split('\n\n\n\n');
  var keys = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    var block = blocks[i].split('\n\n');
    var label = block[0];
    var key = keys[label] = {};

    for (var j = 1; j < block.length; j++) {
        var data = block[j].split(' --> ');
            key[data[0]] = data[1];
    }
  }

  return keys;
}
```

This is the file data we are parsing:

```
journalism.When

2000 --> 219

2003 --> 194

1998 --> 190

2001 --> 173

2004 --> 155

2002 --> 155

1995 --> 144

2008 --> 127

1997 --> 123

1994 --> 117



journalism.Who

Atmos --> 85

J. Geophys --> 77

OECD --> 70

Grossman --> 56

EPA --> 54

PBL --> 49

Krueger --> 45

Stern --> 43

Selden --> 42

Taylor --> 41



journalism.Where

US --> 129

São Paulo --> 115

Brazil --> 104

U.S. --> 76

Germany --> 55

USA --> 45

America --> 42

Italy --> 39

UK --> 39

LA --> 36
```

This is the `fileReader`

```
function readSingleFile(event) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];

      if (file) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
          let src = e.target.result;
          var data = parseData(src);
        }
        reader.readAsText(file);
      } else {
        alert("Failed to load file");
      }
    }
    document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

When parsing the data via a variable for example `var src = 'file contents';` The function works perfectly and it returns three different objects as shown here:

[image]

But if I use the fileReader and the results are different as shown here:

[image]

So it seems as if when using the `fileReader` the text gets formatted or it losses whitespaces. Can anyone spot what the issue is?

Can anyone please advise me on how this could be fixed, if any more examples or if you have any questions please feel free to ask, Thanks.

Comment: You failed to show the FileReader part... What Operating system are you on? Where does the Blob come from? What's the line ending character in  `str`? Ps: From what you gave, it's a [no-repro](https://jsfiddle.net/79b5fc4m/) for me.

Comment: The `FileReader` has been added to the post so you could see it from there @Kaiido

Comment: What about my other questions? What Operating system are you on? What's the line ending character in `str`? Also, what's the encoding of the original file? (even though there seems to be only ASCII characters here...)

Comment: @Kaiido I am using a MacBook. The second question about what's the line ending character in `str` did you mean `src`? The third question It seems to be ASCII. Sorry, I am not the most experienced.

Comment: Your file has two different line ending styles, mac and windows. You can see it in the screen shot posted, `\r\r\n` first the `\r` is a mac line ending followed by `\r\n` which is the windows ending. Your code only accounts for `\n` which is linux line endings, so... you'd need to fix that.